# Nav items not displaying

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where my nav items are not displaying. While not visible, the register and logout nav are 'clickable', and it's invisible but when I hover over it I can click on it and it takes me to register and conversely I can click to logout after I register and am logged in. None of my other nav items are showing up even invisibly for me to click on. There should be register and login nav item displayed for users who haven't logged in, and then a number of nav items after a user logs in.

As you can see in my snippet, when you hover over to the right, there is a link that you can click on, but is invisible. Also as I said, it should be 2 links when user isn't logged in yet.

```css
.navbar-nav li a {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Modify the backgorund color */
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid pink
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("/static/images/jumbo.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 350px
}

.notification {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 50;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.social a {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-twitter {
  color: #00aced;
}

.fa-goggle-plus-g {
  color: #dd4b39;
}

.fa-instagram {
  color: #517fa4;
}

.fa-youtube {
  color: #bb0000;
}

.fa-facebook:hover,
.fa-twitter:hover,
.fa-instagram:hover,
.fa-instagram:hover,
.fa-youtube:hover {
  color: #d5d5d5;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 3.5rem;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #ffffff
}

hr.light {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

hr.light-100 {
  border-top: 1px solid #;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 430px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.upper-container {
  height: 150px;
  background: #7F00FF;
}

.image-container {
  background: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translate(100px, 100px);
}

.image-container img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.lower-container {
  height: 280px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lower-container h3,
h4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: .6;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.lower-container h4 {
  color: #7F00FF;
  opacity: .6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.lower-container p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.lower-container .btn {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  background: #7F00FF;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.lower-container .btn:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #7F00FF;
  border: 2px solid #7F00FF;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class="notification" />
  <style>
    <!-- Add this tag --> {
      % block styles %
    }
    
    {
      % endblock %
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class='navbar-brand' href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}">
        <h5 style="color:red"></h5>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

          {% if user.is_authenticated %} {% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %} {% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="notification" style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css">
              <span>Inbox</span>
              <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
            </a>
          </li>

          {% else %}

          <li class="nav-item">

            <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">
              <span>Inbox</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a>
          </li>
          {% else %}

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
          </li>

          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- HEADER END -->

  <!--Below is individual page will html will be rendered -->
  <hr class="my-4">
  <!--Connect -->
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row text-center padding">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2>Connect</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 social padding">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- FOOTER AREA BEGINS BELOW-->

  <footer>
    <div class="container-fluid padding">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}">
          <hr class="light">
          <p>703-309-9572</p>
          <p>rezazandirz@gmail.com</p>
          <p>100 Street Name</p>
          <p>City, State, 000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <hr class="light">
          <h5>Our hours</h5>
          <hr class="light">
          <p>Monday: 9am-5pm</p>
          <p>Saturday: 10am-4pm</p>
          <p>Sunday: closed(like Chick-fil-A)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <hr class="light">
          <h5>Our satellite offices</h5>
          <hr class="light">
          <p>City, State, 00000</p>
          <p>City, State, 00000</p>
          <p>City, State, 00000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <hr class="light-100">
          <h5>&copy;CupidsCorner.com</h5>
        </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
      ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

  <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. The link that you can click on isn't invisible, it's empty. 2. The link you can click on is a button, not a link. 3. [Please only include the relevant code for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 4. This issue may have something to do with how your backend is set up. When I removed all of the template data, all of the links appeared so this may not be a CSS problem.

Comment: @RaheelJunaid What do you mean with how my backend is set up? I guess that explains why it works on my production version on heroku, but it's not working on my local server... what do you mean by when you removed all of the template data? How do you do that?

Comment: Well, the backend gives a template context or information (I'm assuming you're using Django), which you have implemented using {% if %} statements or the template data. If you remove all of those statements in the Navigation bar, all of the links appear.

Comment: actually when I take all of those if statements out, my links aren't able to connect to my view functions... it's odd because this all works on my production code that's hosted on heroku. I did just buy a new Mac but I transferred everything over. Is it possible a dependency is missing?

Comment: Possibly. If the CSS works on Heroku then it may be a local dev environment issue as you've suggested. Apologies that I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Yes it does work on heroku. How can I figure out if it's a local dev issue?

Comment: Ideally, all of your project dependencies are stored in the `requirements.txt` file automatically. I would double-check that.

Answer (score 1):

You did 2 mistakes -

1. You did not set the background color for the hamburger.
2. You did not set id in here `<div  class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="????"  >`

Code below-

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->


    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


    




    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

    

    

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>
    <style>
    <!-- Add this tag -->
    {% block styles %}

    {% endblock %}
    .navbar-nav  li a{
  padding-left:35px;
  padding-right:10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  color:yellow;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}





/* Modify the backgorund color */ 
.navbar-custom { 
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid pink
} 


.jumbotron{

  background-image: url("/static/images/jumbo.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 350px
}




.notification {

  
  
  text-decoration: none;
  padding:50;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  
}




.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.social a{
  font-size: 4.5em;
  padding: 3rem;

}


.fa-facebook{
  color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-twitter{
  color:#00aced;
}
.fa-goggle-plus-g{
  color:#dd4b39;
}
.fa-instagram{
  color:#517fa4;
}
.fa-youtube{
  color:#bb0000;
}

.fa-facebook:hover,
.fa-twitter:hover,
.fa-instagram:hover,
.fa-instagram:hover,
.fa-youtube:hover{
  color: #d5d5d5;
}



footer {
  padding-top:3.5rem;
  color:blue;
  background-color: #ffffff

}

hr.light{
  border-top:1px solid red;
  width:75%;
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom:1rem;

}

hr.light-100{
  border-top:1px solid #;
  width:100%;
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom:1rem;

}

body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: arial;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
    .card-container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 430px;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
  }
    .upper-container{
    height: 150px;
    background: #7F00FF;
  }
    .image-container{
    background: white;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    transform: translate(100px,100px);
  }
    .image-container img{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
    .lower-container{
    height: 280px;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
    .lower-container h3, h4{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: .6;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
    .lower-container h4{
    color: #7F00FF;
    opacity: .6;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
    .lower-container p{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: gray;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
    .lower-container .btn{
    padding: 12px 20px;
    background: #7F00FF;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
  }
  .lower-container .btn:hover{
    background: transparent;
    color: #7F00FF;
    border: 2px solid #7F00FF;
  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
     
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class= 'navbar-brand'  href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}"><h5 style="color:red"></h5> </a>
        <button class= "navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive"  >
          <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto" >

     
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                
                {% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %}
                {% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}
        

                    <li class="nav-item"  >
                        <a class=  "notification" style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css" > 
                        <span>Inbox</span>
                        <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% else %}

                    <li class="nav-item">

                        <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">    
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
                </li>

            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </nav>

 
<!-- HEADER END -->


<!--Below is individual page will html will be rendered -->



<hr class="my-4">

<!--Connect -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center padding">
     <div class="col-12">
        <h2>Connect</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12 social padding">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER AREA BEGINS BELOW-->

<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}">
            <hr class="light">
            <p>703-309-9572</p>
            <p>rezazandirz@gmail.com</p>
            <p>100 Street Name</p>
            <p>City, State, 000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <hr class="light">
            <h5>Our hours</h5>
            <hr class="light">
            <p>Monday: 9am-5pm</p>
            <p>Saturday: 10am-4pm</p>
            <p>Sunday: closed(like Chick-fil-A)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <hr class="light">
            <h5>Our satellite offices</h5>
            <hr class="light">
            <p>City, State, 00000</p>
            <p>City, State, 00000</p>
            <p>City, State, 00000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <hr class="light-100">
            <h5>&copy;CupidsCorner.com</h5>
        </div>


</footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
      ================================================== -->
      <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

      <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not quite working on my end even after adding the id